# Simple HTACCESS Rule Rewrite wont work

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^shop _new_shopAll.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^shop/new _new_shopNew.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^shop/swarovski _new_shopSwar.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^shop/signature _new_shopSig.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^shop/wedding _new_shopWedding.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^shop/celeb _new_shopCeleb.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^shop/sale _new_shopSale.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^shop/sw3 _new_shopSW3.php [NC]
```

I do not seem to realise why shop just works and everything else works with the same? Do $ or $1 need to be added?

I want this to work

```
/shop?filter=Black = /_new_shopAll.php?filter=Black
/shop/celeb?filter=Black  = /_new_shopCeleb.php?filter=Black
/shop = /_new_shopAll.php
/shop/celeb = /_new_shopCeleb.php
```

Those are separate links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first rule `RewriteRule ^shop _new_shopAll.php [NC]` will also match `shop/new` and replace the link before any of the other rewrites have a chance to touch the link. All the RewriteRules afterwards instead see `_new_shopAll.php`.

You need to add a `$` to the end of the first rule like so:
`RewriteRule ^shop/?$ _new_shopAll.php [NC]`
That way it won't match `shop/new` and the other rules will have a chance to match it.